# How to store a template in an expression in Handlebars.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, handlebars.js

I want to place my templates on several places in the DOM without having to write the jQuery expression over and over again. I want to place my template in the DOM by just typing the variable/attribute {{template}} anywhere in the body.

Is this doable using Handlebars? If not, is there any other way for me to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use HandleBar helpers

[handlebar_helpers](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html)

p.s. dont forget to use safestring else it will be escaped by default

Updating with answer based on ur comment
The link i provided did give out an excellent explanation. However please find below an example.
Assume your need to return a welcome message when a name is given

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('welcome', function(name) {
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(
    "<p>Hi "+name+", welcome to stackoverflow</p>"
  );
});
```

Then calling
    `{{{welcome "sagittarius"}}}` will return

> Hi sagittarius, welcome to stackoverflow

Comment: Can you give an example on how to achieve this using HandleBar helpers?